# Calculus of Variation

Tags: calculus-of-variations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calulus of variations Euler Lagrange equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218121/calulus-of-variations-euler-lagrange-equation)

Find the extremals for the following functionals and discuss whether they provide a minimum or a maximum to the functional.

$$j[y]=\int_0^1 \exp(y)(y')^2 dx $$
subject to the boundary conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y(1)=log(4)$.

I am aware that you have to find the euler lagrange equation to the problem but I am then having trouble solving it for y' and y. Also how do I know whether it provides a min or a max? I'm pretty sure I need to use this,
$$ j[y+f] = \int_0^1(y'+f')^2-(y+f) dx $$
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218121/calulus-of-variations-euler-lagrange-equation